# cs1513 c# expected unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

Hi everyone i'm new to Unity scripting and i cant deal with the problem please someone help me

here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class testScript  : MonoBehaviour
{
    int i = 1;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        for (i = 1; i > 6; i++)
        {

            Debug.Log("value of i = " + i);

        }

        Debug.Log("i'm out of the loop");

    } //the problem is cs1513 c# expected unity here(21.line)

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
```

program i'm using Microsoft Visual Studio

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only missing `}` at the end of the script. The last `}` should close the class `{`. This was likely deleted by you by mistake. Sometimes, Unity does not recognize script change. If this problem is still there after making this modification, simply close and re-open Unity and Visual Studio/MonoDevelop.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class testScript  : MonoBehaviour
{
    int i = 1;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        for (i = 1; i > 6; i++)
        {

            Debug.Log("value of i = " + i);

        }

        Debug.Log("i'm out of the loop");

    } //the problem is cs1513 c# expected unity here(21.line)

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}//<====This you missed.
```